# How to use onChildRemoved in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay so I wanted to know how the `onChildRemoved` works in Firebase Realtime Databse. I am able to add data as soon as the user adds the data  i.e., in realtime. But I want to do the same thing when the user deletes the data. How to proceed with that? I read the documentation but could not get it.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I am able to remove the data by `mRootRef.child("message").removeValue();`
 but I have to go back and come again to this activity to see the changes.

```
private void loadmessage(String class_id, String email_red) {
            messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    messageList.add(message);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   //what to add here??
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: just use onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)  and get the key of that snapshot to check which value is to remove from your parse data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from @mark922 has the gist, but you'll need a few more steps.

When you remove a message from the database, you'll get a `DataSnapshot` of that removed message in `onChildRemoved`. You will need to:

1. Find the corresponding message in your `messageList`.
2. Remove the message from the list.
3. Call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to make the adapter repaint the list/recycler view.

The tricky bit is step 1, because it means you need to be able to find the message. The easiest way to do this is to keep the `DataSnapshot.getKey()` for each message. Since the key of each child node must be unique, there is guaranteed to only be a single message for each key.

A simple way to add this to your current code, is to add a `keyList`:

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then add the key of each `DataSnapshot` to that list as you add the value t `messageList`:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
    messageList.add(message);
    keyList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you have a `keyList` and a `messageList` and the items at each index correspond to each other. So the key in `keyList[0]` corresponds to the value in `messageList[0]`, etc.

That means that in `onChildRemoved` you can look up the index for the message that was removed in `keyList` and then remove that message from both `messageList` and `keyList` based on the index:

```
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    int index = keyList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    messageList.remove(index);
    keyList.remove(index);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

#### A note on message insertions

The above code works only when new messages are always appended to the end of the list. In a simple chat app that may be true. But in more evolved apps, you may also insert data somewhere else in the list.

In that case the `String s` that is passed into `onChildAdded` becomes important, since it is actually `String previousChildKey`: the key of the child *before* which the new child was inserted. To handle this scenario correctly, you should track the order of the items, for example by inserting the key and value in the correct index in their respective lists. At that point you'll also want to handle `onChildChanged` and (more important for this scenario) `onChildMoved`.

All of this is not incredibly complex, but it's quite easy to get something wrong. I'd recommend having a look at the [`FirebaseArray` class from FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java) as an example/source of inspiration.

Comment: Accepted the answer by just looking at the name :) Although it worked too. Thanks Frank!!

Answer (score 3):

Add following code in place of `//what to add here??`

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //what to add here??
    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
    messageList.remove(message);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and deleted data from the console. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to add this to your current code, is to add a keyList:

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then add the key of each DataSnapshot to the keyList as you add the value to messageList:

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    int index = keyList.indexOf(key);

    if (index != -1) {
        messageList.remove(index);
        keyList.remove(index);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```